# need to trigger $swipe event in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-handling, swipe, angularjs-ng-touch

I am using ngTouch for an angular html5-hybrid app.  And one of things that happens that causes bugs it that $swipe will start but not end. 
For example, given the code below: The console will log "swipe started" and nothing else. This generally happens when swiping up off the top of the screen in the iOS simulator.

```
$swipe.bind(angular.element(document.querySelector('#swipeContent')), {
            'start': function() {
                console.log('swipe started');
            },
            'end': function () {
                console.log('swipe ended');
            },
            'cancel': function() {
                console.log('swipe cancelled');
            }
        });
```

So what I was thinking about doing was just employing a setTimeout that ends the swipe after a small amount of time(anyone have a better idea let me know). This means I need to trigger an 'end' event on the element. Anyone know how to do this? below is my first attempt(which doesnt seem to work).

```
$swipe.bind(angular.element(document.querySelector('#slideContent')), {
            'start': function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                     angular.element(document.querySelector('#slideContent')).triggerHandler('end')
            }, 300);
            },
            'end': function () {
                console.log('swipe ended');
            },
            'cancel': function() {
                console.log('swipe cancelled');
            }
        });
```